# Adapting GTK+ to SwiftForth

Tags: c, callback, gtk, forth

SwiftForth-linux has a strictly CLI interface, so attempting to write code to create a custom window required something like [GTK+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B), and I used this.

My problem is in the callback procedure. Writing code which accepts keypresses requires a suitable callback to go with the appropriate signal_connect function.

In translating the C code to Forth I still have one stumbling block involving the event_key structure which I will need for the code of the key pressed.

I take it (but I could be wrong) that the GTK+ system will create it and pass the address to me to insert into a variable and use later, but how is this accomplished?

In the several examples I have there is no mention of a event * or any thing similar as a return. Is there a widget function which will return the address of the event_key structure?

I am almost there, but I need a bit of assistance from someone versed in both GTK+ and C (and hopefully Forth), and any tips would be appreciated.

TCG

In response to the first comment: I need the to access the event_key structure to extract the keycode of the key pressed. How this is presented to the callback function is the mystery to me.

Part of my problem is that in order to translate the C functions into Forth, I need to understand the inner workings of functions like G_CALLBACK(). The code I have seen which was written to receive keypresses had the GtkWidgit * and GtkEventKey * as input parameters to the handler. For example,

```
static gboolean  key_event(Gtk_Widget *widget, GdkEventKey * event)
```

I can write a custom wrapper to put these parameters on the return stack before the handler is executed, but is this what GTK+ would expect?

One additional: "pointer to the function" This term can be used in a confusing fashion. Was it = " the address of the function" or "the address of a variable containing the address of the function"?

Comment: For context, since I don't quite get *where* you are having an issue: what is this for, the `key-press-event` signal handler?

Comment: I know C, but I've only ever used GTK+ from Python, so I can only be of limited help. But the callback you need to supply is a (pointer to a) _function_. When the event you connect to occurs then your callback function is called, and it's passed the event structure as an argument; it may also be passed additional args that you specified in the original connect call. There are some examples in C of supplying callbacks to `gtk_signal_connect()`[here](http://www.gtk.org/tutorial1.2/gtk_tut-2.html)

Comment: `G_CALLBACK` is simply a cast to avoid compiler warnings. There is no magic involved there.